# Android: using custom cover for internal records

Tags: android

My application record some sound and use standard player to playback it.
I would like to know how to add a custom cover art to the audio files and show it via intent.

Comment: Do you mean cover art? Perhaps you could make your question more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there are two ways to add album art to an MP3. The easiest way is to place an image in the same directory as the audio file, and most media players will assume that it is cover art. Some people suggest calling this file "AlbumArt.jpg".

The other way to do this is to embed the art int the MP3 itself. I don't know how to do this myself, but you might find [this](http://www.richardfarrar.com/embedding-album-art-in-mp3-files/) article useful.